# Can't produce a barplot after "casting"

Tags: r

After succesfully performing a cast (using the reshape package) on a small data set I obtain the following frame(e_disp) which is what I am looking for.

```
        Date Code        200g
1 2010/06/01 cg4j 0.519880141
2 2010/09/19 7gv2 0.158999682
3 2011/04/14 zl94 0.294174203
4 2011/05/27 a13t 0.140232549
```

My problem is that I wish to create a barplot which has the values under the column 200g plotted in bars with the x-axis being the date and each bar having the code associated with value. (This could also be on the x-axis above or below the date)

My problem is that I get the following error

"Error in barplot.default(e_disp) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix"

So my questions are
1) Can what I am trying to do be done after using 'cast'
2) If so any suggestions as to how to accomplish this

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easily done with `ggplot2`. Here is an example

```
# generate dummy data
mydf = data.frame(date = 1:5, code = letters[1:5], value = rpois(5, 40))

# plot it using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
pl = ggplot(mydf, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
     geom_text(aes(label = code), vjust = -1)
print(p1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("Date Code x200g
 1 2010/06/01 cg4j 0.519880141
 2 2010/09/19 7gv2 0.158999682
 3 2011/04/14 zl94 0.294174203
 4 2011/05/27 a13t 0.14023254"), header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)
```

Pasting the Date and Code columns separated by linefeed (\n") to make labels:

```
barplot(dat$x200g, names.arg=paste(dat$Date,"\n", dat$Code, sep=""),  ylab=" ")
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I found the first problem which was the col labelled 200g needed a character in front of the 200g myself, but having both labels under the bars is great, thanks !